# Function argument with no default, do I need to check if defined?

Tags: php, function, parameters, arguments

I have a function that requires an argument. My gut tells me to return false if this argument is not set, but do I have to?

```
function myFun($important) {
    echo "PHP is way too kind";
}

myFun();
@myFun();
```

Will this ever be echoed? On linux, windows, with some unusual ini-files?

Better safe than sorry and do this?:

```
function myFun($important) {
    if(!$important) return false;
    echo "PHP is way too kind";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://3v4l.org/UHbMe

In PHP 7.1 and up, PHP will throw an error.  In PHP 7.0 and below, the function will still run and PHP will only emit a warning.

This is just if the argument is not provided.  The argument provided could still be a falsey value like `NULL`, `false`, `0`, or `''` without any error or warning being emitted.

Comment: Ok.. I want the function to return false for `NULL`, `false`, `0`, or `''` would if(!$important) return false;`do the job, or do I need `!isset()` or something else?

Comment: `if (!$important)` should work fine for that as that will check for any falsey value and you've already defined $important as the function argument.

Comment: @OnklMaps Note that you won't be able to tell the difference between `myFun()` and `myFun(null)`.

Comment: @Barmar, well, with the OP code, myFun() would emit an error/warning and myFun(null) would not, so there would be a major difference in 7.1+.

Comment: Yes, PHP can tell the difference, but the program itself can't tell the difference in an `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

you can say that, this argument can be null

```
function myFun($important = null) {
   if(is_null($important)) {
      echo "PHP is way too kind";      
   } else {
      echo $important;
     }
}
```

or it may have a default value

```
function myFun($important = "very important") {
   echo $important;
}
```